# Partition by with date and Row_Num(Rank_Num)

Tags: sql-server

i would like help to solve this problem.

The **OUTPUT** Field is what i would like my "**ROW_NUM**" Field to look like.

i would like to use **row_num** or **rank_num** and **over partition** by if possible.

```
SELECT 
    [P_ID] ,
    [DATE],
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [P_ID] ORDER BY [DATE]) AS ROW_NUM
FROM #TEMP
```

[image]

```
P_ID    DATE    ROW_NUM     OUTPUT
3385    2012-02-02  1       1
3385    2012-02-03  2       2
3385    2012-09-24  3       1
3385    2012-09-25  4       2
3385    2013-11-12  5       1
3385    2013-11-13  6       2
3385    2013-11-14  7       3
3385    2013-11-15  8       4
3385    2014-09-09  9       1
3385    2014-09-10  10      2
3385    2014-09-11  11      3
3385    2015-11-11  12      1
3385    2015-11-12  13      2
3385    2015-11-13  14      3
5538    2012-02-02  15      1
5538    2013-11-12  16      1
5538    2013-11-13  17      2
```

Comment: Tag dbms used. (Perhaps SQL Server?)

Comment: Post your sample data as text not as image. Also, i doubt that the sql query returns that.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I'm guessing its not, it returns the row_num and he asks how to make the output field

Comment: @sagi. Currently `ROW_NUM` shows just consecutive values. Certainly not what `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [P_ID] ORDER BY [DATE])` returns because `P_ID` is not unique. It's completely unclear what OP actually needs.

Comment: My desired result is the output filed and not the row_num

mssql (t-sql)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to enumerate consecutive dates for each `pid`.  You can do this by subtracting a row number from the dates -- difference is constant for consecutive dates.  The rest is jut `row_number()`:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by pid, grp order by date)
from (select t.*,
             dateadd(day,
                     - row_number() over (partition by pid order by date)
                     date) as grp
      from #temp t
     ) t;
```

Note:  this is SQL Server syntax (that looks like the database you are using.  Date functions vary based on the database.

Comment: Hi, this almost workes but if htere is another month 2013-12-31 and then 2014-01-01 then there will be another "1" as an output and i do not want that because there are no "bigg gap" like more then 5 days between the days

Comment: @Nils . . . This should recognize consecutive dates, regardless of year and month boundaries.

Comment: It does not. For some reason when there is a new month i get a new nr 1 ?

Comment: @Nils . . . If you want months to start over, then you need to change the `partition by`, say to `partition by pid, year(date), month(date)`.

Comment: if you just add 2013-12-31 and the 2014-01-01 i still get a new "1" even if i take your edvice?